# ng-bind-html doesn't prevent cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss

I used ng-bind-html in order to prevent cross site scripting,
read about [sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) and found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007807/angularjs-cross-site-scripting-preventing) and [another good discussion](http://java.dzone.com/articles/angularjs-how-handle-xss).

Although, i did't work for me, can you please help me in figure out why?

HTML:

```
<p class="big-text" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(message)">
```

JS:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};
```

when i'm adding the following line

```
<img src="x" onerror="alert('cross')">
```

and adding it to a message i can see it rendered in the DOM, and when i'm refreshing the page i can see the message.

[image: dom image]

and the popup is shown:
[image]

can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is this cross-site how? Looks like you are calling it in the same page.

Comment: every user that will open the site will get this alert, instead of the alert it can be malicious script

Comment: Liad, this is not cross-site, it is your own site accepting untrusted user input (you should sanitize the content of the message at the server, not at the client).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, it's not XSS on its own.

Second, `$sce.trustAsHtml` does exactly the opposite of what you thought - it, in fact, instructs Angular to "trust" that the HTML is safe - not to sanitize.

To sanitize, you need to add `ngSanitize` as a dependency to your app, and `ng-bind-html` directly to `html_code` (without `to_trusted`).

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"])
  .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
     $scope.html_code = '<img src="x" onerror="alert(\'cross\')">';
  });
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="html_code"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

After using Sanitize i change my code and used **getTrustedHtml** instead **trustAsHtml**, it runs the sanitize on controller.

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.getTrustedHtml(html_code);
};
```

And it solves my issue.