# How to prevent a textbox from executing script?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, security, xss

In my application i have a search textbox which uses two way binding (ng-model). As soon as i append following script as a search keyword, it starts executing it. i find an Alert message pop up. If this can be resolved using $sanitize, can you give me a simple example how can i use it and what is $sce is? I refereed Angularjs official doc for $sanitize but that is extremely confusing to understand.

```js
 <script> alert("Hi") </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs + cross-site scripting preventing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007807/angularjs-cross-site-scripting-preventing)